# Why does my java Scanner.nextLine() code sometimes skip a line?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to understand why my java code doesn't behave as I expect it to do.

I want to print the question once, wait for the user to input their answer, then decide whether to loop back or proceed depending on the answer.

When I run the code below, the question gets printed twice, and the loop didn't stop and wait for user input after its first run.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

String answer = "";

while (!answer.equals("Yes") && !answer.equals("No")){
    System.out.println("abc1");
    System.out.println("Do you want to quit the game? Answers: y/n");
    System.out.println("abc2");
    System.out.println("abc3");
    answer = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("abc4");
}
```

I don't think I need a second .nextLine(), because the first one already consume the end of the input line (\n). But for the sake of experimenting, I modified the code by adding an extra .nextLine() (as shown below). Two problems with this new code:

- On the first run (first loop), the code skips the first .nextLine() and waits for user input at the second .nextLine() (I can tell this is the case because "abc3" gets printed before I, as a user, can input anything).
- Starting from the second loop, the code prints "abc2", wait for user input, prints "abc3", then wait for user input again.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

String answer = "";

while (!answer.equals("Yes") && !answer.equals("No")){
    System.out.println("abc1");
    System.out.println("Do you want to quit the game? Answers: y/n");
    System.out.println("abc2");
    answer = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("abc3");
    answer = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("abc4");
}
```

I modified the code further (`answer = input.nextLine();` vs just     `answer = input.nextLine();`) and still get the same behaviors.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

String answer = "";

while (!answer.equals("Yes") && !answer.equals("No")){
    System.out.println("abc1");
    System.out.println("Do you want to quit the game? Answers: y/n");
    System.out.println("abc2");
    input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("abc3");
    answer = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("abc4");
}
```

What do I get wrong here?

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You declare `input` and `answer` but use `playerInput` and `quit` inside your loop

Comment: Perhaps you could post a [mre]. One in which `playerInput` is defined, and which you have tested definitely reproduces the behaviour you are describing.

Comment: @sourcloud Sorry I wrote an simplified example code of what I'm trying to do but forgot to change the variable names. I've updated the codes. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @khelwood I wrote a simplied example of what I was trying to do. I've made updates to my example. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @Dxml Simplified examples are great, but once you've changed it, *you* need to run the simplified version and make sure it reproduces the problem you are describing before you post it.

Comment: @khelwood Thank you! I completely overlooked where I actually made the mistake. I was able to run the simplified code, but not my original. Not the advice I was looking for, but definitely one I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where the mistake was! I left a `.nextInt()` elsewhere in my code but forgot I needed to consume the end of the line (`\n`). My (first) `.nextLine()` finished what had been left off by the `.nextInt()` without me realizing this was happening.